# What's the easiest way to convert milliseconds to readable String in Java Spring

Tags: java, milliseconds, human-readable

How to convert during(milliseconds) from long to readable String in Java, such as 5 minutes and 2 seconds or 2 hours if no trailing minutes or seconds?

I have tried TimeUtils, but it still requires a little script to concatenate strings.

Comment: There isn't anything for this in the main Java libraries, so this would probably be asking for a library -- which might be closed.  (Note also that this is something sensitive to the languages used by the consumers.)

Comment: You might have a look at java.time.Duration: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationWords instead:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DurationFormatUtils;

...
DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationWords(milliseconds, true, true);
...
```

The result will be:
`X days Y hours Z minutes` without leading or trailing zero elements

Detail: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DurationFormatUtils.html#formatDurationWords-long-boolean-boolean-

Answer (score 2):

## `java.time.Duration`

Use `Duration` to represent a span of time not attached to the timeline, on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "PT5M2S" );
```

Parse your count of milliseconds as a `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMillis( myMillis ) ;
```

You can [manipulate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) the [standard ISO 8601 output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) from the [`Duration#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toString()).

```java
String output =
        d
                .toString()
                .replace( "PT" , "" )
                .replace( "H" , " hours " )
                .replace( "M" , " minutes " )
                .replace( "S" , " seconds " )
                .stripTrailing();
```

> output = 5 minutes 2 seconds

If you want to get more fancy, such as using singular for a value of one, use the `Duration#to…Part` methods.

Comment: Great answer! I recommend using [`String#trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim()) which has been available since the beginning. [`String#stripTrailing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripTrailing()) was introduced with Java 11.